# How the request.getRemoteUser() works and the remote username value is stored?

Tags: java, authentication, tomcat, servlets, httprequest

I have Tomcat authentication (form authentication) in my application. After successful authentication, I am able to get the username from the `request.getRemoteUser()` method in my servlet.

Where I can find `request.getRemoteUser()` code? How does this work? Where has the RemoteUser has been set and stored? Since HTTP requests are stateless and execute independently, how this giving the username in all subsequent requests?

Comment: Since this is your third question on the subject, can you clarify what kind of details are you looking for? Stephen's comment on your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70255777/11748454) explains that the username is stored in a session referenced by a session cookie. HTTP is stateless, but you often build stateful protocols on top of it.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz  http requests are stateless then how its works , request.getRemoteUser() returning username in all request . if username is stored in session , then how the request is getting username from session. where the session was stored . where i can find getRemoteUser() code ? i checked with the httpRequest class it is an interface ,containinly only abstract methods then how its working and how the methods returning values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to deal with authentication, every context in Tomcat has a [`Valve`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/Valve.html) that extends [`AuthenticatorBase`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/authenticator/AuthenticatorBase.html), that:

1. tries to authenticate the user using the data in the `HttpServletRequest`,
2. checks the authorization requirements for the URL,
3. if authentication is required, but absent, sends an appropriate response to the browser, asking for authentication. This usually means a `401` response with a [`WWW-Authenticate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/WWW-Authenticate) header for most authentication methods or a `302` redirect to the login page for form authentication.
4. if authentication is present, but the access is not authorized, it sends a `403` response.
5. otherwise calls [`Request#setUserPrincipal`](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/6f9eb19a47ed8d414d718a782d671daa345d5940/java/org/apache/catalina/connector/Request.java#L1951) and proceeds with the next valve.

For the details check the [`AuthenticatorBase#invoke`](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/6f9eb19a47ed8d414d718a782d671daa345d5940/java/org/apache/catalina/authenticator/AuthenticatorBase.java#L500) method.

Most authentication methods are based on the [`Authorization`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/valve.html#Authentication) header sent by the browser (the form authenticator uses request parameters).

If a session is present (e.g. you called `HttpServletRequest#getSession`), the authenticated user will be cached in the session and subsequent requests will not need to authenticate any more. You can force session creation using the `alwaysUseSession` attribute on the authenticator valves (cf. [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/valve.html#Authentication)). The server can recognize the presence of a previously established session through many methods:

1. A `JSESSIONID` [`Cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) header in the request,
2. A `jsessionid` path parameter in the URL,
3. If you use TLS, the TLS session can be also be used to detect the appropriate HTTP session.

Comment: If this answers your question, you can mark it as accepted (it's the check mark sign near the answer).

Comment: done  @Piotr P. Karwasz